# Find all solutions to $\frac{a+b}{b} = \frac{a}{a+b}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I want to find all solutions to $\frac{a+b}{b} = \frac{a}{a+b}$. I have plugged this into a calculator which tells us that if we solve for $a$, without loss of generality, we obtain

$$a = - \frac{b}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$$

and vice versa. I am not sure how to show this, however. I have tried a couple of different things. For example,

**Method 1:**

$$\frac{a}{a+b} = \frac{a+b}{b} \implies (a+b)^2=ab \implies a+b = \pm \sqrt{ab}$$

**Method 2:**

$$\frac{a}{a+b} \cdot \frac{a-b}{a-b}= \frac{a+b}{b} \cdot \frac{a-b}{a-b} \implies \frac{a(a-b)}{a^2-b^2}=\frac{a^2-b^2}{b(a-b)} \implies \big( a^2-b^2 \big)^2 = ab(a-b)^2$$

But so far neither of these methods are shedding any light for me. Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming $ab \ne 0$ let $x=a/b$ and show it satisfies $x^2+x+1=0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To begin with, let us assume that $b\neq 0$ and $a\neq -b$.

Now we can multiply both sides by $b(a+b)$ in order to obtain

\begin{align*}
(a + b)^{2} = ab & \Longleftrightarrow a^{2} + 2ab + b^{2} = ab\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow a^{2} + ab + b^{2} = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \left(a + \frac{b}{2}\right)^{2} + \frac{3b^{2}}{4} = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \left(a + \frac{b}{2}\right)^{2} = -\frac{3b^{2}}{4}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow a + \frac{b}{2} = \pm\frac{bi\sqrt{3}}{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow a = -\frac{b \pm bi\sqrt{3}}{2}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps !

Comment: It helped a lot! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have $(a+b)^2=ab$ or $a^2+ab+b^2=0$. If $a\ne b$, multiply by $(a-b)$, get $a^3-b^3=0$. So $a=b\omega$ where $\omega$ is one of the cube roots of $1$. The possibility $a=b$ does not work, the other two work.

**Answer:** $b$ is any non-zero number, $a=b\omega$ where $\omega$ is one of the two non-1 cube roots of $1$.

Comment: Your answer is $a=b \omega$? But then $a^3-b^3 = (b\omega)^3-b^3=b^3-b^3=0$, a contradiction, according to your own answer...